# Unexpected type: BINARY

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-table-api

I am trying to read parquet files via the Flink table, and it throws the error when I select one of the timestamps.

My parquet table is something like this.

[image]

I create a table with this SQL :

```sql
    CREATE TABLE MyDummyTable (
              `id` INT,
              ts BIGINT,
              ts_ltz AS TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ(ts, 3),
              ts2 TIMESTAMP,
              ts3 TIMESTAMP,
              ts4 TIMESTAMP,
              ts5 TIMESTAMP
            )
```

It throws an error when I select one of the **ts2**, **ts3**, **ts4**, **ts5**

The error stack is this.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected type: BINARY
    at org.apache.parquet.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.vector.ParquetSplitReaderUtil.createWritableColumnVector(ParquetSplitReaderUtil.java:369)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.createWritableVectors(ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.java:264)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.createReaderBatch(ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.java:254)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.createPoolOfBatches(ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.java:244)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.createReader(ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.java:137)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.createReader(ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.java:73)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.impl.FileSourceSplitReader.checkSplitOrStartNext(FileSourceSplitReader.java:112)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.impl.FileSourceSplitReader.fetch(FileSourceSplitReader.java:65)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.FetchTask.run(FetchTask.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcher.runOnce(SplitFetcher.java:138)
    ... 7 more
```

**My Current appproach**

I am currently using this approach to jump over the problem but it does not seem a legit solution since I create two columns in the table.

```sql
        CREATE TABLE MyDummyTable (
          `id` INT,
          ts2 STRING,
          ts2_ts AS TO_TIMESTAMP(ts2)
        )
```

Flink Version: 1.13.2
Scala Version: 2.11.12

Comment: Which version of Flink are you using?

Comment: Flink version is 1.13.2. Thanks for pointing it out. I will update the question too.